# Java all child element reading in XML

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I want to read all link and title at the same time to array list?

```
<rootNode>
    <image>
        <link>http://imagelink/</link>
        <title>This is the title</title>
    </image>
    <movie>
        <link>http://movielink/</link>
        <title>This is the title</title>
    </movie>
</rootNode>
```

Code below works fine but, where there are different child nodes it can make code too big.

I don't want multiple for, I want something that looks clean!

```
    ArrayList XTimeStamp = new ArrayList();
    Node libraryTagNode, libraryDataNode;
    Element libraryTagElement, libraryDataElement;
    NodeList libraryTagList,libraryDataList;

    try {
        File file = new File("computer.txt");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(file);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList imageLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("image");
        NodeList movieLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("movie");  

        for (int s = 0; s < imageLst.getLength(); s++) {
            libraryTagNode=bookLst.item(s);


            if (libraryTagNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                libraryTagElement = (Element) libraryTagNode;

                libraryTagList = libraryTagElement.getElementsByTagName("link");
                libraryDataElement = (Element) libraryTagList.item(0);

                libraryDataList = libraryDataElement.getChildNodes();
                String timeStampX=libraryDataList.item(0).getNodeValue();

                libraryTagList = libraryTagElement.getElementsByTagName("title");
                libraryDataElement = (Element) libraryTagList.item(0);

                libraryDataList = libraryDataElement.getChildNodes();
                String timeStampY=libraryDataList.item(0).getNodeValue();

                XTimeStamp.add(timeStampX+" "+timeStampY);

            }

        }
    for (int s = 0; s < movieLst.getLength(); s++) {
            libraryTagNode=bookLst.item(s);


            if (libraryTagNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                libraryTagElement = (Element) libraryTagNode;

                libraryTagList = libraryTagElement.getElementsByTagName("link");
                libraryDataElement = (Element) libraryTagList.item(0);

                libraryDataList = libraryDataElement.getChildNodes();
                String timeStampX=libraryDataList.item(0).getNodeValue();

                libraryTagList = libraryTagElement.getElementsByTagName("title");
                libraryDataElement = (Element) libraryTagList.item(0);

                libraryDataList = libraryDataElement.getChildNodes();
                String timeStampY=libraryDataList.item(0).getNodeValue();

                XTimeStamp.add(timeStampX+" "+timeStampY);

            }

        }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Please edit it to indicate the order in which you want to visit the nodes.

Comment: Can you switch to using XPath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to roll the two loops into one somehow as this is certainly a cumbersome way to do it as it is now.

The answer is to use XPath. I would suggest you search for `<title>` elements whose `parent` holds a `<link>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Use XPATH - see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure on what your asking but if you want to get all the link nodes in a NodeList and all the title nodes in a different nodelist you could try  [XPath](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=java%20xpath&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CD4QFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F2811001%2Fhow-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java&ei=b7bwTp5AqtjhBPDu9LIB&usg=AFQjCNHFH8jr_LBpFDPWzaE-7KMLnDNt2Q&sig2=7o4PQ1YNIlo2BujozJl2HQ) using "//link" and "//title" as your XPath expression